# How to add new schema/table to Postgresql publication (for all tables) without downtime?

Tags: postgresql, replication

I want to add new tables to existing FOR ALL TABLES publication on PostgreSQL 11.

When I am trying to alter publication, I will get information that publication is defined for all tables, however it doesn't include new tables.

Publication cannot be removed as there is a lot of subscribers and it is not viable to take down publication every time there is a new table and then recreate dozens and dozens of subscriptions...

I am sure that there is somewhere different option, but I cannot find anything in the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot.

You need to create a publication per table/schema and then you can add/remove it.

Fairly useless to use FOR ALL TABLES, so be aware.